# What is the correct way to fix a leaky drain trap that is not detachable?

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak, drain

I have a shower that has a leak in the drain trap. From this picture, it appears to be leaking from the drain to pipe connection to the shower pan, but that part is actually fixed as it was leaking too. It is actually leaking now from the connection between the pipe and the drain trap turn in the center of this picture:

[image: drain]

Is there a good epoxy or cement I can put around the connection to seal it? It is a slow leak. If not, what is the best way to fix it?

Comment: maybe the best course of action is to remove the white pipe and use toilet flange over the shower base "nipple" ... maybe a rubber toilet flange exists that would fit tight

Comment: That is an interesting thought. This is a fairly low pressure area and might work. I'm a bit hesitant though as I'd hate for the rubber to start leaking in a year and have to remove the drywall again. I'm also not sure how I would I would ensure pressure is kept up. It would definitely be "Unique"

Answer (score 2):

Wow, someone butchered that install. You really should think about replacing the trap and the shower drain. You mentioned that both were leaking but the pipe into the drain has been fixed and now only the trap leaks. They will leak again. I've never seen a drain connected like that. The drain looks like it was modified to take the pipe, poorly.

If you can pinpoint the leak, clean and rough up the surface.Widen the leak area a bit to make room for the epoxy. Then try some marine epoxy and coat the area. Follow the directions for curing time. this might buy you a little time.

Comment: You are not kidding about someone screwing up this install. I have already fixed the top here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/195164/what-is-the-correct-material-to-reseal-a-shower-pan-to-a-drain-pipe/   My question is this: Would a putty epoxy be good enough you think? I am fairly sure at this point that its on that drain connection. entering the elbow. I am going to verify a few more times. I feel the mixable two part would be very hard to get up in that area around the lip, but I suppose it would be doable. If the putty would work, it would be much easier to pack around.

Comment: Just to be clear from your comment: The leak is in the connection between the two pipe pieces, so it would be hard to roughen it up as you say.

Comment: @David maybe you can get a strip of sandpaper back there and pull it back and forth.

Comment: @David I was wondering if this was the other end of that disaster.

Comment: @Jasen - It sure is. Its a bit of a mystery to me how both the pan and the joint started leaking about the same time, but from the build of of residue I had to wipe off, it's obvious they are both leaking. The plumbing in the restroom is seriously messed up. I'm considering just gutting it, but still hoping to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

what should be there is a clamping flange fitting like those used on bath-tubs.  not a piece of pipe glued into a hole it doesn't fit with mortar and epoxy. I see some damage to the edge of the hole but it doesn't look too bad.